# ng-repeat nested data repeats through empty values

Tags: angularjs

I have activity controller in rails that renders the below json output.

```
{"id":3,"trackable_id":6,"trackable_type":"Movie","owner_id":1,"owner_type":"User","key":"movie.create","parameters":{},"recipient_id":null,"recipient_type":null,"created_at":"2015-12-30T12:31:24.765Z","updated_at":"2015-12-30T12:31:24.765Z",
  "owner":{"id":1,"email":"peter@peter.nl","provider":null,"uid":null,"name":"Peter Boomsma","username":null}},

{"id":2,"trackable_id":5,"trackable_type":"Movie","owner_id":1,"owner_type":"User","key":"movie.create","parameters":{},"recipient_id":null,"recipient_type":null,"created_at":"2015-12-30T11:55:06.766Z","updated_at":"2015-12-30T11:55:06.766Z",
  "owner":{"id":1,"email":"peter@peter.nl","provider":null,"uid":null,"name":"Peter Boomsma","username":null}},
```

In my activity template I have this ng-repeat,

```
%ul{"ng-repeat" => "activity in activities"}
  %li{"ng-repeat" => "owner in activity"}
    Full Name: {{owner.name}}
```

But it looks like the ng-repeat is looping through every value in both the parent and child object because the output looks like this,

```
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name: John Doe
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name: John Doe
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
Full Name:
```

Is this approach of rendering incorrect or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be just a single owner per activity:

```
%ul{"ng-repeat" => "activity in activities"}
  %li // Remove the ng-repeat here
  Full Name: {{activity.owner.name}}
```

This should work for you.

Apologies! Not sure about the exact syntax used here

Comment: hm! so you can just "string" them. Well that's good to know :).

Comment: @PeterBoomsma Happy to help. Also, do not forget to mark this answer as accepted so that it may help fellow developers with similar queries!

Comment: You're right. The answer was to fast for me to accept previously ;).